# what does the STD in STD_LOGIC stand for in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I have searched on the internet and in our university's books to find what 'std' stands for.

I would really like to find out what it stands for.

Comment: probably _standard_

Comment: that seems a little weird, but so far it's the best explanation yet.

thank you

Comment: definitely _standard_

Comment: Published as IEEE Std 1164-1993, IEEE Standard Multivalue Logic System for VHDL Model Interoperability (Std_logic_1164). Notice the commonality of the Std in the standard number, IEEE Standard and Std_logic_1164.  In version 4.2 (1992) of the package (part of the standard) `-- *** industry standard logic type ***` precedes `SUBTYPE std_logic IS resolved std_ulogic;` while in the -2008 version of the package the preceding comment has been changed to `-- logic state system  (resolved)`, throwing away a clear indication std stands for standard.

Comment: See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 16.8.2 Interpretation of the standard logic types *This subclause (16.8.2) defines how a synthesis tool shall interpret values of the standard logic types defined in IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164 and of the BIT and BOOLEAN types defined in STD.STANDARD. ...* IEEE Std 1164 has been subsumed into the VHDL standard.

Answer (score 1):

'std' stands for 'standard', in reference of the Standard Package

Source:

- https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/stdpkg.html
- http://www.vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00066.htm
- http://slideplayer.com/slide/4646019/15/images/43/Libraries+Library+Std;+Contains+the+Following+Packages:.jpg